# Python - How to check an API's modules

Tags: python, api, module

I have the API Arcgis
and i import arcgis.gis

I want to find what this module has in terms of tools
so for example i know it has
.tags but how would i know if it has .feature_layers (because apparently that doesn't exist). So simply in an API how do i know what is available for me to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would read the documentation, however if their is none available, before looking at the source code you can do the following

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> help(mymodule)
>>> dir(mymodule)
>>> mymodule.__dict__
```

Some more inspection can be done with the ...inspect class...  (Check out this script, I did not write it, but also don't remember where I got it)

```
import inspect
import mymodule

def get_function_markdown(function):
    return inspect.getdoc(function)


def parse_class(_class):
    for name, data in inspect.getmembers(_class):
        print '%s :' % name, repr(data)


def parse_module(module):
    """See what you can get in  module."""
    for name, data in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if name == '__builtins__':
            continue
        if inspect.ismodule(data):
            print "ismodule"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isclass(data):
            print "isclass"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
            parse_class(data)
        elif inspect.ismethod(data):
            print "ismethod"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isfunction(data):
            print "isfunction"
            print get_function_markdown(data)
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isgeneratorfunction(data):
            print "isgeneratorfunction"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isgenerator(data):
            print "isgenerator"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.istraceback(data):
            print "istraceback"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isframe(data):
            print "isframe"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.iscode(data):
            print "iscode"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isbuiltin(data):
            print "isbuiltin"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isroutine(data):
            print "isroutine"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isabstract(data):
            print "isabstract"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.ismethoddescriptor(data):
            print "ismethoddescriptor"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isdatadescriptor(data):
            print "isdatadescriptor"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.isgetsetdescriptor(data):
            print "isgetsetdescriptor"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        elif inspect.ismemberdescriptor(data):
            print "ismemberdescriptor"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)
        else:
            print "Unknown"
            print '%s :' % name, repr(data)


def main():
    """Testing."""
    parse_module(mymodule)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```